# Using ListView in AsyncTask

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-asynctask

Hello I am trying to use `ListView` in AsyncTask but I am having some problems in my application and it is giving me runtime error.

My application gets tweets using `Twitter4j` then displays them in a `ListView`. I was wondering if this could be done in a continuous way and the tweets would display one by one.

This is what I have till now: (I did some debugging and the error was in the `onPostExecute` method in the last line! The tweet was not being displayed , error below code)

```
package com.example.sentimentmining;

import java.util.*;

import com.example.sentimentmining.R.color;
import com.example.sentimentmining.R.drawable;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import twitter4j.*;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class DisplayResults extends Activity {
private ListView listView ;
private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;  
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.linearlayout);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    setupActionBar();
        }

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(TwitterOpinion.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    printTweets task = new printTweets();
        task.execute(new String[] { message });


}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void setupActionBar() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_results, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



private class printTweets extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... q) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      


    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
      .setOAuthConsumerKey("xxxxxxx")
      .setOAuthConsumerSecret("xxxxxxxx")
      .setOAuthAccessToken("xxxxxxx")
      .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("xxxxxxx");
    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
    Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

        Query query = new Query(q[0]);
        QueryResult result = null;
        do{
            try {
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                }
                result = twitter.search(query);
            } catch (TwitterException e) {                  e.printStackTrace();
            }
            List<twitter4j.Status> tweets = result.getTweets();

        for (twitter4j.Status tweet : tweets) {
            TextView tv=new TextView(getApplicationContext());

            tv.setTextSize(25);
            String tweetAndUser = "@" + tweet.getUser().getScreenName() + ":" + tweet.getText();
            tv.setText(tweetAndUser);

            return tweetAndUser;}
         } while ((query = result.nextQuery()) != null);
        return null;

    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        String[] x = new String[] {result};
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.linearlayout, x); 
          listView.setAdapter( listAdapter );
        }   


}

}
```

Error Code:

```
02-16 14:18:27.045: E/AndroidRuntime(26873): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

02-16 14:18:27.045: E/AndroidRuntime(26873): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-16 14:18:27.045: E/AndroidRuntime(26873):    at com.example.sentimentmining.DisplayResults$printTweets.onPostExecute(DisplayResults.java:138)
02-16 14:18:27.045: E/AndroidRuntime(26873):    at com.example.sentimentmining.DisplayResults$printTweets.onPostExecute(DisplayResults.java:1)
02-16 14:18:27.045: E/AndroidRuntime(26873):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
02-16 14:18:27.045: E/AndroidRuntime(26873):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
02-16 14:18:27.045: E/AndroidRuntime(26873):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
02-16 14:18:27.045: E/AndroidRuntime(26873):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-16 14:18:27.045: E/AndroidRuntime(26873):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-16 14:18:27.045: E/AndroidRuntime(26873):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
02-16 14:18:27.045: E/AndroidRuntime(26873):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-16 14:18:27.045: E/AndroidRuntime(26873):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-16 14:18:27.045: E/AndroidRuntime(26873):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
02-16 14:18:27.045: E/AndroidRuntime(26873):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
02-16 14:18:27.045: E/AndroidRuntime(26873):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anyone help please?
Thank you

EDIT:
The XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
    </ListView>
    <TextView 
 android:id="@+id/rowTextView"   
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
 android:padding="10dp"  
 android:textSize="16sp" >  
</TextView>  

</RelativeLayout>
```

Updated Code:

```
package com.example.sentimentmining;

import java.util.*;

import com.example.sentimentmining.R.color;
import com.example.sentimentmining.R.drawable;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import twitter4j.*;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class DisplayResults extends Activity {
    private ListView listView ;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;  
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.linearlayout);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        setupActionBar();
            }

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(TwitterOpinion.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        printTweets task = new printTweets();
        task.execute(new String[] { message });


    }
    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    private void setupActionBar() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_results, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    private class printTweets extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        private ArrayList<String> tweetList;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... q) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub      

        ArrayList<String> tweetList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
          .setOAuthConsumerKey("4SXDBWYxC8ssmWuxCHdQ")
          .setOAuthConsumerSecret("GxLDXg6EYti50c4EWI8AvWf6fKaOBDOZxksgvYafEVs")
          .setOAuthAccessToken("85058363-gC2zVaJ3KsniZNYIDFv6Ohc5zWwG34c7FQezDxTP1")
          .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("OnZnol2z27P3tqo9HwwGLzMKD6zZhwvRyFWWsCqWJsv9S");
        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
        Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

            Query query = new Query(q[0]);
            QueryResult result = null;
            do{
                try {
                    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                    }
                    result = twitter.search(query);
                } catch (TwitterException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                List<twitter4j.Status> tweets = result.getTweets();

            for (twitter4j.Status tweet : tweets) {
                String tweetAndUser = "@" + tweet.getUser().getScreenName() + ":" + tweet.getText();

                tweetList.add(tweetAndUser);
                }
            } while ((query = result.nextQuery()) != null);
            return null;

        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String test) {

            listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.linearlayout, tweetList); 
            listView.setAdapter( listAdapter );
            }   


    }

}
```

Updated Error:

```
02-16 15:36:22.995: E/AndroidRuntime(9017): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-16 15:36:22.995: E/AndroidRuntime(9017): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-16 15:36:22.995: E/AndroidRuntime(9017):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)
02-16 15:36:22.995: E/AndroidRuntime(9017):     at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:466)
02-16 15:36:22.995: E/AndroidRuntime(9017):     at com.example.sentimentmining.DisplayResults$printTweets.onPostExecute(DisplayResults.java:124)
02-16 15:36:22.995: E/AndroidRuntime(9017):     at com.example.sentimentmining.DisplayResults$printTweets.onPostExecute(DisplayResults.java:1)
02-16 15:36:22.995: E/AndroidRuntime(9017):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
02-16 15:36:22.995: E/AndroidRuntime(9017):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
02-16 15:36:22.995: E/AndroidRuntime(9017):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
02-16 15:36:22.995: E/AndroidRuntime(9017):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-16 15:36:22.995: E/AndroidRuntime(9017):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-16 15:36:22.995: E/AndroidRuntime(9017):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
02-16 15:36:22.995: E/AndroidRuntime(9017):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-16 15:36:22.995: E/AndroidRuntime(9017):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-16 15:36:22.995: E/AndroidRuntime(9017):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
02-16 15:36:22.995: E/AndroidRuntime(9017):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
02-16 15:36:22.995: E/AndroidRuntime(9017):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Line 124 is: listView.setAdapter( listAdapter );

Comment: @Raghunandan listView.setAdapter( listAdapter );

Comment: @Raghunandan Still same error.

Comment: make sure your tweetList is not empty. The error is not the same yes its a NPE yes but your list seems empty

Comment: do check the edit that should be enough for you to understand and fix your problem. if you want to displat username and tweet is a separate textview then you need to use custom adapter

Comment: All is there and I just rechecked (debugging mode) right now the tweetList is not empty. I updated the XML file.

Comment: the answer is also there in my post. pls read it and then try to fix it. this is all i can do to help

Answer (score 0):

From your comments line 138 is `listView.setAdapter( listAdapter );`

`listView` is not initialized hence null. You forgot

```
listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

Also you are updating ui from `doInbackground`

```
tv.setText(tweetAndUser); // not possible from background thread.
```

Update ui in `onPostExecute` and use Activity Context for

```
TextView tv=new TextView(DisplayResults.this);
```

Edit:

```
class printTweets extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,ArrayList<String>>
{

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String>doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ...// rest of the code 
    ArrayList<String> tweetList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (twitter4j.Status tweet : tweets) {
            String tweetAndUser = "@" + tweet.getUser().getScreenName() + ":" + tweet.getText();
            tweetList.add(tweetAndUser);
            }
    return tweetList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DisplayResults.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, result); 
        listView.setAdapter( listAdapter ); 

    }
```

Comment: Ok let's say I removed the TextView and I want to pass over multiple tweets to be displayed in the listView. Is there a way to store every tweet then pass them to the onPostExecute function for them to be displayed? Thank you

Comment: @RanaAkel use a `ArrayList<String> tweetList = new ArrayList<String>();`. Then add tweets `tweetList.add(tweets)` in a for loop. And then use the tweeList instead of string array x

Comment: After doing what you suggested we got an error.
We are adding multiple tweets in the ArrayList<String> but after we debugged, we noticed that it was adding only 1 time and not multiple tweets. And then we are getting a runtime error before even reaching the onPostExecute

Comment: @RanaAkel that means your doing it wrong. Post the updated code and the error. The error could not be bcoz of what i suggested

Comment: I updated the code. Please check and give us any suggestions. Thank you

Comment: @RanaAkel what is line 118. `tweetList` is not initialized. see this `new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: tweetList.add(tweetAndUser);
(sorry if the lines aren't the same, I removed some comments just to save place here)

Comment: @RanaAkel initialize the list dude, You have only declared not initialized `tweetList` . re- read my previous comments `ArrayList<String> tweetList = new ArrayList<String>();` declaration and initialization

Comment: Hello Again, I am a "dudette". But ok I initialized all the list and now after the application fetches all the tweets it won't display them.
02-16 15:23:29.725: E/AndroidRuntime(6889):  at com.example.sentimentmining.DisplayResults$printTweets.onPostExecute(DisplayResults.java:136)
Line 136 is: listView.setAdapter( listAdapter );

Comment: @RanaAkel show the updated code. if you declared and initialized list in doInbackground it will local to that method and you will need to return the list in doInbackground. then use the list for the adapter. Seems i will to post the whole code

Comment: @RanaAkel and comments are not the best place to post the updated stacktrace and avoid commenting further. post the edit and i will reply the same by editing in my answer